# Javascript Form not posting anything into the body

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The Javascript form submits all the information except for the body part.

```
<form action="javascript:;" method="post" enctype="text/plain"  onSubmit="this.action='mailto:'
                      +document.getElementById('friend1').value+','
                      +document.getElementById('friend2').value+','
                      +document.getElementById('friend3').value+
                      '?cc=test@test.com&subject=Tester and space&body=testit';">

<input type="Email" id="friend1" value="" required placeholder="1st friend's email"/><br>
<input type="Email" id="friend2" value="" required placeholder="2nd friend's email"/><br>
<input type="Email" id="friend3" value="" required placeholder="3rd friend's email"/><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The part that is suppose to change the contents of the body located in the "onSubmit" action in the form:

```
&body=testit
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Everything works, expect for the body part. Nothing happens in the body when you submit the form.

Comment: Perhaps it's the unencoded whitespace in your URL (try replacing " " with "%20")? Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: Hey, just tested it using IE and noticed that it works fine there, but it doesn't work in Chrome. Very strange.

Comment: Placing unencoded spaces in a URL puts you in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) territory, so it's not that surprising that different browsers would handle spaces differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your spaces in the subject with %20. I remember having an issue with this years ago. It has to do with the encoding.

```
&subject=Tester%20and%20space
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but it's not the subject that is the problem, its the body.

Comment: Did you try the solution? EDIT: i'm almost positive you are not supposed to have blank spaces in the subject of mailto. This is why you may be getting mixed results. The string is terminating before it reaches ?body, which is why it is missing on some browsers.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome, still doesn't work, but it works fine in IE.

Comment: @dean - marking an answer as accepted will significantly reduce traffic to your question. If the answer isn't what you're looking for, don't mark it as accepted.